# Integrate a php module in a Java web application

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, apache2, tomcat6

I am having one enterprise application developed using j2ee technology. I also have some php application. I want to merge the php application in my enterprise application to enhance the functionality without rewriting the code in j2ee. Could anyone please suggest me how to do this. I did some research on this and found following options

1. PHP & Java bridge - In this I will run tomcat behind apache server. The php module will be in apache and j2ee app in tomcat. This seems to be the opposite of how I would want my app to run. As the user registers in j2ee app and will also use the module build in php. So I would want my tomcat server to be oin front.
2. Install php on tomcat and run the php module in tomcat server. I tried many times to configure this with PHP5+ and tomcat6+ but not able to do that. I also could not find proper php & tomcat version combination which works together.

Please help me to find the best option (open for any new options as well) keeping application performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

running the PHP part on Apache httpd and the java part on Tomcat "behind" it is not that wrong. The fact that Tomcat is behind apache server is only a matter of connection flow, but from a user POV /forum/page.php will be handled by PHP, while /supercomputation/dothat will be handled by java.

The only problem is how you put the two together on the same page, if you need to, cause in this case only server side includes, iframes or javascript pop on my mind.

Another approach is to install PHP on a separate server, even another httpd on a different port, eventually listening only on 127.0.0.1, and then use a java server side component to "fetch" PHP output and merge it in the page generated by tomcat.

It might sound a hack, but it's not that hard at all, is already supported by many frameworks, and I've seen enormous web sites in production with a java based "frontend" that aggregated contents coming from other PHP and Python subsystems.

Whatever solution you decide to adopt, you'll need to setup some coordination between the two systems ... for example, single authentication for users. How to do that heavily depends on how those applications are designed, and will probably need some tuning here and there.